# Can a Git repo's upstream be set to a local clone of the same repo?

Tags: git

I have one repo in `/home/user/reponame` (Repo 1). I have then cloned this repo to `/tmp/reponame` (Repo 2). Is it possible to change the upstream repo of Repo 1 to Repo 2?

Other questions I have seen suggest branches, but they are not what I am looking for here. When I do `git checkout -b test --track /tmp/reponame/master`, I get the error `/tmp/reponame/master is outside repository`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't use term 'upstreams' for any repository-wide setting. Only individual branches have an upstream in Git terminology, and it can only be set to some other branch, because its purpose is to as a shortcut/default for commands such as `git merge <otherbranch>`. (Your `git checkout` command is also entirely built around working with branches.)

Instead, you're probably looking for **'remotes'**, which store repository URLs. Every new clone stores its source URL in a remote named `origin`. So if you want repo 1 to be able to push to repo 2, you can use `git remote add` or `git remote set-url` (depending on whether a remote by that name already exists or not):

```
git remote add origin /tmp/reponame
git fetch origin
```

Alternatively:

```
git config remote.origin.url /tmp/reponame
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

This is often followed by updating the per-branch upstreams, to make `git pull` etc. work:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to="origin/master" master
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the origin within the checkout command? I am working in a limited environment.

Comment: No, because the checkout command has nothing to do whatsoever with repository-wide settings. (The checkout command is for managing branches and files in the working tree.) If you actually don't have access to core git commands, then add the corresponding settings directly to the `.git/config` file. You can use the clone's /tmp/reponame/.git/config as an example.